# How to use an import to only one function?

Tags: python, import

How can I `import` a module in `Python`, but only to **one** function?

My imagination:

```py
def func():
    localize from myModule import helperFunc # localize means "to this scope only: "
    helperFunc("do something magical")       # but it doesn't exist

try:
    helperFunc("do something magical")
except NameError:
    print("'helperFunc' doesn't exist at this scope") # this would get run
```

The problem here is that `localize` doesn't exist.  Is there something in `Python` to simulate that?

Comment: An import inside a function definition is already local to that function.

Comment: Names created in a function are local by default. That includes imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just import modules normally:

```py
def choose5(lst):
    from random import choices
    # choices is imported here
    return choices(lst, k=5)

print(choose5([1, 2, 3]))
# choices is not imported here
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def my_now():
    from datetime import datetime
    return datetime.now()

try:
    print("Success", datetime.now())
except NameError:
    print("NameError occurred", my_now())
```

Running the above code will give you the output

```
NameError occurred 2020-11-06 21:20:19.930863
```

`datetime` was scoped to the `my_now` function. Trying to calling `datetime.now()` directly failed, so the function `my_now` was called and that was able to call `datetime.now()` successfully.